# Stream containing Html encoding and special characters issue

Tags: .net, encoding, stream

My program reads a web page content with by issuing a HttpWebRequest and reading a stream from HttpWebResponse.
I looked at the html content and saw this.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

So I did this:

```
Encoding CorrectEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, CorrectEncoding);
result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

But inside `result` instead of seing Björn as in the browser I see Bj?rn.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpWebResponse's headers

```
response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType]
```

or

```
response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentEncoding]
```

instead of looking into stream.

Comment: doesn't work ContentEncoding is always null for me plus I learned from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/feroze_daud/archive/2004/03/30/104440.aspx that this is the best solution to get the encoding

Comment: @Para Seems you haven't carefully read this blog **If this header is not present, or if a “charset=” token is not present in the header value, then you need to look at the header of the HTML page**